# Texstudio hangs when opened in Macbook Pro running High Sierra version 10.13.1

Tags: texstudio, macos

I am using Texstudio for last few years and find it very appealing. But after the last Mac OS update to 10.13.1, Texstudio freezes. I have to force quit it everytime. Kindly suggest me how to get rid of it as it's urgent for me.

Comment: I would recommend also making a report on the project page: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/?source=navbar. The maintainers of TXS are more active there, and you're more likely to get the help you need.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the version of TeXStudio, whenever I place my cursor on top of a `\cite{ref}` piece of text in an open document, the screen glitches, then the computer freezes, followed by a teal-coloured screen and finished with the login screen.

I also tried compiling TeXStudio myself, and the problem persists.

OS X version 10.13.1

This is what I can find on "console" seconds before a crash

```
Dec 1 14:01:09 C02SQ0PLFVH4 texstudio[17779]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[mach_recv] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked 
Dec 1 14:02:05 C02SQ0PLFVH4 texstudio[17786]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[mach_recv] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
```

I have also reported this bug here: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/2327/